# .htaccess 301 redirect: access new domain and view old domain with all structure maintained, only with the new url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to access http://newdomain.co/ and view all the content from http://olddomain.com/shop/, but with the url bar showing the new domain and keeping all the old structure.

The e-commerce platform is OpenCart. In the .htaccess located under /shop/ folder I currently have this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /shop/
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm not used to htaccess codes, so explain well, please :)

Comment: Please note I want to keep ALL the structure, so accessing http://newdomain.co/login should show the page located at http://olddomain.com/shop/login

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_proxy to do this. And you can't use mod_proxy unless it's loaded in your apache server. If it's loaded, you can add this to the htaccess file that's in the **document root of the newdomain.co host**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} newdomain\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://olddomain.com/shop/$1 [L,P]
```

If nothing happens, or you're getting redirected to the old domain, then you don't have mod_proxy loaded.

If both domains are using the *same document root*, then you don't need to use mod_proxy, you just need this in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} newdomain\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/$1 [L]
```